# How to log django-kronos tasks with logging module?

Tags: django, logging

I have switched from celery to dramatiq and celery beat to django-kronos and now I am stuck - I am not able to figure out, how to make tasks run by kronos to log using the logging module.

Is it even possible or what is the best practice to log progress of django-kronos tasks?